# как привести к нормальному виду pubdate в rss-reader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rss

Делаю rss-reader, не знаю как привести pubdate к виду которому я хочу. 
По умолчанию pubdate имеет вид "Tue, 06 Aug 2019 00:00:00 +0300"

как из этого сделать формат dd.MM.yyyy

В гугле необходимой информации не нашел.

Привожу код контроллера

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
    var RSSFeed = new List<RSS>();
                foreach (var url in db.Source.Where(c => c.id != null ).Select(c => c.URL))
                {
                    WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
                    string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString(url);
                    var fromEncoding = Encoding.Default;
                    var bytes = fromEncoding.GetBytes(RSSData);
                    var toEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    RSSData = toEncoding.GetString(bytes);

                    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(RSSData);
                    var RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")
                                       select new RSS
                                       {
                                           Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                                           Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                                           PubDate = (string)x.Element("pubDate")
                                       });

                    RSSFeed.AddRange(RSSFeedData);
                }

        ViewBag.RSS = RSSFeed;
        return View();
       }
```

View:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>

                <th>Publish Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSS)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="@item.Link">@item.Title</a></td>
                <td>@item.PubDate</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Models:

```
 public class RSS
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Вообще, в .NET есть встроенные [средства](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication?view=netframework-4.8) для работы с RSS. Смотрите там класс [SyndicationFeed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed?view=netframework-4.8) и пр.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что мне это даст? более быструю работу приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените тип свойства `PubDate` на `DateTime`.

И далее:

```
PubDate = (DateTime)x.Element("pubDate")
```

Если это не сработает, то можно использовать:

```
PubDate = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("pubDate").Value)
```

Однако, работоспособность этого кода зависит от текущей культуры.
Вероятно, лучше всего будет указать культуру явно:

```
PubDate = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("pubDate").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

И далее выводим дату в желаемом формате:

```
<td>@item.PubDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

Это простейший вариант, но он зависит от текущей культуры.
Лучше задать формат явно:

```
<td>@item.PubDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")</td>
```

PS: и здесь тоже можно задать культуру явно.

Comment: Не думал что элементы rss ленты можно получить в любом формате, который тебе нужен. Всё сработало.